# Increasing Focus Pool size as a non-storm or leaf druid

Tags: class-feature, druid, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

Druids have access to focus points, which are spent to cast order spells. A druid starts off with a single focus point and a maximum focus pool size of 1. Druids can improve the size of this pool with the Wind Caller, Invoke Disaster and Impaling Briars feats, but they require the druid be of the storm or leaf orders. Is there any way for a druid to get a larger focus pool without being in either of those orders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Take a multiclass dedication, and choose multiclass feats that grant additional focus points.  Focus points from all feats add together into a combined pool, of up to 3 points maximum, even if they're from different classes.

P. 302 "Focus Points from Multiple Sources":

> It's possible, especially through archetypes, to gain focus spells and focus points from more than one source. If this happens, you have just one focus pool, adding all the focus points together to determine the total size of your pool.
>
> ...
>
> Focus points are not differentiated by source; you can spend any of your Focus Points on any of your focus spells.

Comment: The druid also has a feat allowing them to take another druid subclass, and pick the leaf or storm feats afterwards

Answer (score 1):

At 1st level, choose the Storm or Leaf druidic order and get 2 FP. At 2nd level, get the Order Explorer feat and choose the Wild order. In this way, you get a Wild druid with 2 FP and you can take the Storm druid feats.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour] for an intro to how we do things around here.  It looks like this answer doesn't answer the question - the OP wants to know how to expand their focus pool *without* being Storm or Leaf, but you're suggesting that they just join one of those orders anyway.  If I've misunderstood, or if you're intending to suggest that doing things the way the question specifies is a bad idea, please edit your answer with more details to make it clearer why it's a good idea to ignore part of the question's requirements.